# I'm a novice in\at

Tags: differences, nouns, prepositions

hi!
Could you tell me please what is correct?

I'm a novice in/at travelling.
I'm a novice in/at English.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Next time, look it up. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in). None of the cited cases apply so @PephenKinD is correct. [ELU rules](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) request that you first try to lookup the answer before posting.

Answer (score 3):

"I'm a novice at travelling," and "I'm a novice at English" would be correct. However, a smoother way of expressing the former would be, "I'm a novice traveller."